# One-button transition to gradient

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a hover effect for a button, the button before the hover only has an outline and its name inside, after the hover I would like it to have a transition to my background which is gradient, I tried several ways but it's not working .
Note: I am modifying an element of the "Elementor" Plugin in WordPress.

```css
ul li {
  font-family: "Poppins", Sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
  margin: 0px 20px 50px 20px;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  color: var( --e-global-color-11a2147);
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
  border-color: var( --e-global-color-c49c864);
  border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}

ul li:hover {
  background-color: transparent;
  background-image: linear-gradient( 90deg, #0081FF 0%, #5DE0E6 100%);
  color: #FFFFFF;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
  <li>Third</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hey please add html code too know the button code is an `a` or `button` tag.

Comment: I guess using transition in gradients is not supported for now as the color needs to be changed from one to another, it can't change from one to two different colors or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this fro transition, since transition is not available for linear gradient

```css
ul li {
    font-family: "Poppins", Sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 500;
    padding: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
    margin: 0px 20px 50px 20px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: var( --e-global-color-11a2147);
    border: solid black 2px;
    border-color: var( --e-global-color-c49c864);
    border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 2;
    transition: .5s ease-in-out;
}

ul li:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    background: linear-gradient( 90deg, #0081FF 0%, #5DE0E6 100%);
    transition: .5s ease-in-out;
    z-index: -1;
}

ul li:hover {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    border: solid transparent 2px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

ul li:hover:after {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
  <li>Third</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It seems to work but when I try to modify it in Elementor it doesn't work, even entering "!important".